# gradient boosting- features contribution

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there a way in python by which I can get contribution of each feature in probability predicted  by my gradient boosting classification model for each test observation. Can anyone give actual mathematics behind probability prediction in gradient boosting classification model and how can it be implemented in Python.

Comment: Have you checked `estimators_` property? It contains a `ndarray` of `DecisionTreeRegressor`.

Comment: Thank you, that thing will work for gradient boosting regression trees. So now I can have a reason code for regression problem. But I am still confused about the classification one.I have a binary classification problem. Do you know if I can use train_score feature of gradient boosting anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go bud, this is exactly what you're looking for :)
https://github.com/slundberg/shap

One note though, you mention you want to see how each feature contributed to a probability which is going to be very hard to do since it's usually a combination of features that is determining the probability. Either way, I think the package above will show you what you want to see.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I was desperately looking for this.However I want to know if this thing will also work for a scikit learn gradient boosting classifier.If it does it will just save me some time.Once again thanks a lot.

Comment: @MrinalMahajan I don't think it's currently working with sklearn. Honestly I would just use "LightGBM" or "XGBoost" (He just added feature interaction functionality to this implmentation which LightGBM doesn't have yet). You should be able to easily use these packages with what you have. Once you have your data pre-processed then it doesn't really matter which implementation you use.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `feature_importances_` property. Very easy.

Comment: that would just give importance of each feature, i need to know how much each feature contributed in computing the probability of each instance. Something similiar to what treeinterpreter does for decision trees and random forest model.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Shapley values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapley_value). There is a [python package](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) as well which does the approximation and should provide you a detailed breakdown.